# Strictly Convex geodesic Space

Tags: functional-analysis

It is possible to give an example of a strictly convex geodesic space which is not a uniformly convex geodesic space?

Comment: Yes. Recall that uniformly convex spaces are reflexive, then think: do you know a space that is strictly convex (or perhaps admits a renorming making it so) that is not reflexive?